# Is having a "display: table-cell" element not inside a "display: table-row" element a valid construct?

Tags: html, css

In a sample web application I have to work on, I noticed that some elements had a `display: table-cell` style but their parent don't have `display: table-row`.

To me thats seems wrong, but I'm not sure at all.

Hence this question: Is this a valid construct ? What problems can it cause, if any ?

Thank you.

Here is an example of what I meant:

```
<div style="display: block">
  <div style="display:table-cell">
    <p>Some content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: +1 This should be moved to `code review`. Personally I think using `display: table-row` on anything other than a `tr` is a bastardization of proper CSS/HTML. :)

Comment: @anonymousdownvotingislame: Thanks for the upvote. I'm not sure that really fits code-review however. Imho, it is not a big code who needs to be validated or improved but a question about the validity of a particular construct.

Comment: Contrary to @anonymousdownvotingislame I'd say that `display:table-cell` was specifically introduced to display non-tabular data as it would be inside a table cell. In my opinion this is totally valid as long as you don't obfuscate tabular data by putting it inside divs instead of tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm kind of parroting Faust who was kind enough to find the specs (but seems to have now removed his answer)...

Yes, it is (probably) valid.

> Document languages other than HTML may not contain all the elements in
>   the CSS 2.1 table model. In these cases, the "missing" elements must
>   be assumed in order for the table model to work. Any table element
>   will automatically generate necessary anonymous table objects around
>   itself, consisting of at least three nested objects corresponding to a
>   'table'/'inline-table' element, a 'table-row' element, and a
>   'table-cell' element.

From 17.2.1 Anonymous table objects, 
http://www.w3.org/Style/css2-updates/css2/tables.html#anonymous-boxes

This could be read as anonymous boxes will be created in non-HTML languages that don't have the right construct but I would assume that it will generate anonymous table objects in HTML as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to find to appropriate quote in the standard ! It perfectly answers my question.